# Installing "SSOAP package" on Rstudio (Mac OS) - getting error

Tags: xml, r, soap, rstudio, rcurl

I want to connect my R script to a SOAP web server in order to extract data. Im an R newbie but a decent programmer.

- I have installed Rstudio
- I installed RCurl and XML2 packages.
- Now Im trying to install the

  SSOAP package. I downloaded the .tar.gz file from here:
  http://www.omegahat.org/SSOAP/

Next on Rstudio and used the "Install" button under "Packages", see here:

I get this error after:

```
 > library("RCurl", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")
Loading required package: bitops

> library("xml2", lib.loc="/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library")

> install.packages("~/Desktop/R/downloads/SSOAP_0.9-0.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

  ERROR: dependencies ‘XML’, ‘XMLSchema’ are not available for package ‘SSOAP’
* removing ‘/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.2/Resources/library/SSOAP’ 
  Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘/Users/XX/Desktop/R/downloads/SSOAP_0.9-0.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like two dependencies are missing. `install.packages('XML')` should fix the first one (since CRAN still hosts the XML package).  XMLSchema appears to have been de-listed from CRAN.  But you should be able to download and install the .tar.gz like you are trying with SSOAP: http://www.omegahat.org/XMLSchema/.